# UITableview Height is not adjusting using UITableViewAutomaticDimension

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have tableview inside tableview cell , I am using UITableViewAutomaticDimension in heightForRowAt, tableview height is not adjusting automatically. I have to calculate cell height manually. 
Any idea ?

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: In order to make UITableViewAutomaticDimension work you have to set at least a constraints for a control either top or bottom relative to cell container view.

Comment: Do you want to load all your "inner tableview" or "cell'tableview without scroll" and dynamic height?

Comment: add constrain properly in your tableview cell. From the top of items to bottons of high height of component will be dynamic. then and then i will manage.

Comment: I need to load cell'tableview without scroll" and dynamic height

Answer (score 2):

You are missing either bottom or top constraint.
Consider you have to add label in table cell, then you have give both top and bottom constraint to label (make line number 0).
It will automatically increase the size of table cell according to label text.
Don't forgot to set estimatedRowHeight.

Answer (score 0):

To get automatic cell height work correctly you must hook all your constraints properly from top to bottom in the cell Xib , or if you're creating constraints in code , that's how auto-layout can calculate the height automatically

Answer (score 0):

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 50.0
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Set all constraint like bottom, top, left, right.

[image]

Comment: it will work for labels  . I need to add UITableview inside cell not just label.

Comment: _WHY_? Why would you want to do that?

Comment: any solution for this to work with custom views such as uitableview ? it only works for labels ?